# Injury during training session, after 2 months still feel the pain

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, kickboxing

2 months ago I went to Muay Thai training session. I forgot my bandages and went on training. After the session I felt a little bit of pain in my wrist. The next day I had BJJ training. Everything went fine till the next morning, the pain in my wrist increased.

I can still feel the pain today. Would postponing the training sessions help? What do you recommend?

Kindly yours

Comment: I'm not pro medical but my metacarpals injury lasted for 3 months (I didn't postpone sessions).

Comment: You haven't described the pain.

Comment: If I turn with my wrist I can feel it. I can't do push ups because the pain is really annoying. I feel pain when there is pressure on my wrist. I hope this is enough.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question belongs in MA:SE. You're asking for medical advice, not the advice of an experienced martial artist.  You may wish to consider revising the question to highlight martial arts (for example, "What BJJ techniques will not strain my metatarsals?", or "How can I adapt my BJJ training to compensate for an injured wrist?").

Comment: Lets see, a few months ago I suffered an injury. It hasn't healed and is impacting my training negatively. What should I do? I know, I'll ask the intertubes! Go to a doctor and get it checked already.

Comment: If the question can be edited to bring it back more to MA it can be reopened.   Otherwise the answer starts with "talk to a Doctor."

Comment: Physiotherapist - most times doctors will give you a pill if that. Unless they are sports specialists, they don't understand and can't tell you how to make an injury better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you go to see either a doctor or a physiotherapist.